# Java and Javascript Blowfish

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, cryptography

I need to send some data encrypted with Blowfish from a java-based server to a client. I can successfully encrypt data but I can't decrypt it on the client side.

Here is my java code:

```
byte[] kd = key.getBytes("UTF-8");

SecretKeySpec ks = new SecretKeySpec(kd, "Blowfish");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ks);

byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String str = new String(encrypted, "UTF-8");
```

As for js library I decided to use [this](http://sladex.org/blowfish.js/) one.

```
out = blowfish.decrypt(code, skey, {cipherMode: 1, outputType: 0})
```

As a result I get some strange characters. What's wrong with my code?

**UPD:**
This code works perfectly:

```
byte[] kd = key.getBytes("UTF-8");

SecretKeySpec ks = new SecretKeySpec(kd, "Blowfish");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ks);

byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String str = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted), "UTF-8");
```

JS:

```
out = blowfish.decrypt(code, skey, {cipherMode: 0, outputType: 0})
```

Comment: Could be a couple of things, but my guess would be one of these: 1) the key is different (perhaps because of encoding? it's a little weird to use a string directly as a key). 2) The IV is different (CBC mode requires an IV which you never specify directly. Do you know what the default is? Is it the same between the two libraries?) 3) Your JS code isn't using CBC mode or PKCS5 padding (what exactly is "cipherMode: 1"?)

Comment: The key is the same. May be you're right about encoding. "cipherMode: 1" means CBC. However, I don't know what kind of padding this JS library uses.

Comment: `String str = new String(encrypted, "UTF-8")` this can't work. The output of encryption are arbitrary bytes which generally are not a valid UTF-8 sequence. Use Base64 or Hex here.

Comment: Another issue with your code is that without a MAC it's most likely vulnerable to padding oracles. Such an oracle would allow an attacker to use your server as a helper to decrypt the data without knowing the key.

Comment: Relevant article: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending text with `\u0000` bytes in it to a browser can lead to all kinds of odd problems. That's why you should encode the data BASE64, send it to the client and then decode it locally.

Another issue is `new String(encrypted, "UTF-8");` since the encoded byte array will contain illegal UTF-8 sequences. Try `new String(encrypted, "iso-8859-1");` instead, it's a 1:1 encoding for arbitrary bytes. But again, the 0 bytes could confuse some component in between.